# How to convert a numeric column in pandas to a string with comma separators?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, series

I want to convert a column that has values like 1234567.89 to 1,234,567.89. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can format your column by doing this:

```
df['new_column_name'] = df['column_name'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

But keep in mind that the new column will contain strings, not floats.

Comment: when I do that, the output df.dtypes says "Object". I was expecting string. Is this normal?

Comment: Pandas refer string as Object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Diego Mora. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.